# Troubles with gentoo version on the robot Nao

Tags: gcc, makefile, gentoo

I'm trying to install some software directly on the robot to have better access to the hardware (like microphones and camera). The problem is that there is no make, no gcc, nothing. I searched on internet on how to install gcc but nothing. All pages I found say it comes with gentoo distribution. Is there a way to install them? and if possible also offline?
There is a virtual machine provided with the robot equipped with the building tools I can execute the ./configure and make of the software but when I copy the content to the robot I can't run make install since make is missing.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way to do that is to install my program do a different folder than / and the data will be organized as it should be (bin lib include and share folders will be created) and I just need to merge the created folders with the ones on the target robot in /usr

./configure --prefix=/path/to/empty/folder

make

make install

finally copy the /path/to/empty/folder content to /usr on the robot

Answer (score 0):

The virtual machines comes with gcc, make and all needed stuffs.
It provides you a way to build your binary targetting NAO, then you just copy them to your real robots. And it should works.

Alexandre
PS: Installing gcc and ... on the robot is technically feasible, but it will require a lot of time to compile and ...

Comment: How can I know what is put exactly where? I'm struggeling to install portaudio AND pyaudio which depends on portaudio. Now both are compiled and I tried to move all I could to the right place but I still have the error in Python when I try to import pyaudio "Build and install portaudio first"